JasperReports Server Bitnami Docker Image Running in Azure App Service Custom Web.xml
I am using the Bitnami JasperReports image v8.2.0 from https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/jasperreports in a docker container running in an Azure app service.
My Docker configuration file is:
version: '3.8'

services:
  jasperreports:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/jasperreports:8.2.0
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - 'jasperreports_data:/bitnami/jasperreports'
      - "${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/site/wwwroot/config:/bitnami/jasperreports-mounted-conf"
    environment:
      - JASPERREPORTS_USERNAME=***
      - JASPERREPORTS_PASSWORD=***
      - JASPERREPORTS_DATABASE_TYPE=postgresql
      - JASPERREPORTS_DATABASE_HOST=bon-prod.postgres.database.azure.com
      - JASPERREPORTS_DATABASE_PORT_NUMBER=5432
      - JASPERREPORTS_DATABASE_USER=***
      - JASPERREPORTS_DATABASE_PASSWORD=***
      - JASPERREPORTS_DATABASE_NAME=jasper
      - JASPERREPORTS_SMTP_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
      - JASPERREPORTS_SMTP_PORT_NUMBER=587
      - JASPERREPORTS_SMTP_PROTOCOL=smtps
      - JASPERREPORTS_SMTP_USER=***
      - JASPERREPORTS_SMTP_PASSWORD=***
      # Additional environment variables for verbose logging
      - BITNAMI_DEBUG=true
      - JASPERREPORTS_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "5"

volumes:
  jasperreports_data:

I have added WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=true as an app setting to enable storage in the Azure App Service.
I am getting a CORS error when calling the rest endpoint from my front-end domain. I struggled with a similar issue for weeks about 3 years ago and had a similar Stack Overflow question. Back then I was installing on a bare Linux server and resolved the issue using the web.xml below which has the CORS filter added (where sub.domain.com is my real sub-domain, of course):
<filter>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
        <!--  Update allowed origins and remove localhost for non-dev environments -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
            <param-value>https://sub.domain.com</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
            <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,PUT,OPTIONS,DELETE,PATCH</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
            <param-value>Cache-Control,X-Suppress-Basic,Origin,Accept,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Pragma,accept-timezone,withCredentials,X-Remote-Domain,X-Is-Visualize,x-jrs-base-url,Content-Disposition,Content-Description,Content-Type,X-Requested-With,Accept,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Connection,Host,Authorization,Options</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
            <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials,Authorization</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
            <param-value>300</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

So I have SFTP'd the web.xml file to the /site/wwwroot/config folder on the Azure App Service to replace the Bitnami Container's built in web.xml as per the documentation on Bitnami's Docker Hub.
However, this has resulted in error:
https://bon-rpt.greydom.com/jasperserver/JavaScriptServlet 403 (Forbidden)
XMLHttpRequest.send @ JavaScriptServlet:52
ajax @ JavaScriptServlet:425
(anonymous) @ JavaScriptServlet:442
(anonymous) @ JavaScriptServlet:490Understand this errorAI
JavaScriptServlet:158 Failed to retrieve CSRF token
csrfTokenRetrieveFailed @ JavaScriptServlet:158
(anonymous) @ JavaScriptServlet:486
xhr.onreadystatechange @ JavaScriptServlet:421
XMLHttpRequest.send
XMLHttpRequest.send @ JavaScriptServlet:52
ajax @ JavaScriptServlet:425
(anonymous) @ JavaScriptServlet:442
(anonymous) @ JavaScriptServlet:490Understand this errorAI
content_script_bundle.js:1 Attempting initialization Mon Dec 02 2024 21:49:04 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
login.html:1 <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"> is deprecated. Please include <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">Understand this warningAI
JavaScriptServlet:158 Failed to retrieve CSRF token

I am assuming that this is because my existing web.xml does not work within the Docker container.
How can I rather get the container's web.xml, and simply add the CORS filter, remembering that my Docker Container is in an Azure App Service?

If you have a local Docker setup, you can pull and run the same Bitnami JasperReports image locally.

Navigate where web.xml is located and copy the file docker cp and then add the CORS Filter and deploy the modified web.xml to Azure app service.

Unfortunately, modifying the existing web.xml did not work. It caused other issues, like CSRF errors and other strange things.
Thus, I solved it by using Nginx as a reverse proxy:
version: '3.8'

services:
  jasperreports:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/jasperreports:8.2.0
    volumes:
      - 'jasperreports_data:/bitnami/jasperreports'
      - "${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/site/wwwroot/config:/bitnami/jasperreports-mounted-conf"
    environment:
      - JASPERREPORTS_USERNAME=***
      - JASPERREPORTS_PASSWORD=***
      - JASPERREPORTS_DATABASE_TYPE=postgresql
      - JASPERREPORTS_DATABASE_HOST=bon-prod.postgres.database.azure.com
      - JASPERREPORTS_DATABASE_PORT_NUMBER=5432
      - JASPERREPORTS_DATABASE_USER=***
      - JASPERREPORTS_DATABASE_PASSWORD=***
      - JASPERREPORTS_DATABASE_NAME=jasper
      - JASPERREPORTS_SMTP_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
      - JASPERREPORTS_SMTP_PORT_NUMBER=587
      - JASPERREPORTS_SMTP_PROTOCOL=smtps
      - JASPERREPORTS_SMTP_USER=***
      - JASPERREPORTS_SMTP_PASSWORD=***
    
 nginx-proxy:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    volumes:
      - "${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/site/wwwroot/nginx-conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
    depends_on:
      - jasperreports

And nginx.conf:
server {
    listen 8080;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://jasperreports:8080; # Forward to JasperReports container
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        # Add CORS headers
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://***.greydom.com' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
        # Handle preflight OPTIONS requests
        if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://***.greydom.com';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain';
            return 204;
        }
    }
}


Here you need to retrieve the existing web.xml file from the Bitnami JasperReports container, edit it to add the CORS filter, and ensure the modified web.xml is properly injected back into the container at runtime.

Navigate to the App Service instance. Select Development Tools > SSH. open the SSH terminal to access the container's shell.

locate the web.xml file - /opt/bitnami/tomcat/conf/web.xml 
Add the CORS Filter Configuration:
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>https://sub.domain.com</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,PUT,OPTIONS,DELETE,PATCH</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Cache-Control,Origin,Accept,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Authorization</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

Upload the modified web.xml file to the /site/wwwroot/config directory on the App Service.

This caused other errors, like CSRF and weak password errors, so I took another approach as per my answer below.
